# How can I have no styling on the text input for one form but style the input for another?

Tags: html, css, forms, textbox, styling

I need the text inputs for each form to be styled differently but it still applies text css rules to both forms. The current code makes it look like this;

```css
.mail-form {
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}

.apply-form {
text-align: left;
margin-left: 2vh;
}
input[type=text] {
width: 80%;
}
input[type="text"] {
padding: 1vh;
margin-left: 4vh;
}
```

```html
<form class= "mail-form">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<form class="apply-form">
<p>First Name:</p>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
</form>
```

I need the mail form to look like this;

```css
.mail-form {
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form class= "mail-form">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Notice the text box stays that size, I need the apply form to look like this;

```css
.apply-form {
text-align: left;
margin-left: 2vh;
}
input[type=text] {
width: 80%;
}
input[type="text"] {
padding: 1vh;
margin-left: 4vh;
}
```

```html
<form class="apply-form">
<p>First Name:</p>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
```

How can I have these text inputs without the rule for the apply form affecting the rule for the mail form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just add the class in front of the `input` fields

Answer (score 2):

You should only need to prefix your Inputs with the appropriate class

```css
.mail-form {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.apply-form {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 2vh;
}

.apply-form input[type="text"] {
  padding: 1vh;
  margin-left: 4vh;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<form class="mail-form">
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form class="apply-form">
  <p>First Name:</p>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
</form>
```

Comment: Did you find this answer useful? If so please accept it